# Using DOJO with RESTful web services

Tags: asp.net, rest, dojo

I have built a RESTful web service using ASP.NET HttpHandler, when running the web service project im redirected to the default page from which I can choose to download the DOJO code for my Client app.

[image]

here is a code snippet from the downloaded file:

```
function PickrWebService(){ self = this; }

PickrWebService.prototype = {
self: null,
urlString: "http://AYMAN/Handler.ashx",
CreateUser:function(Email,Username,Password,FirstName,Surname,Birth,Gender,Mobile,Picture,Address,successFunction,failFunction,token) {
    var data = { 'interface': 'PickrWebService', 'method': 'CreateUser', 'parameters': {'Email':Email,'Username':Username,'Password':Password,'FirstName':FirstName,'Surname':Surname,'Birth':Birth,'Gender':Gender,'Mobile':Mobile,'Picture':Picture,'Address':Address}, 'token': token };

    var jsonData = dojo.toJson(data);
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: self.urlString,
        handleAs: 'json',
        postData: jsonData,
        load: successFunction,
        error: failFunction };
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
},
CheckUserExistence:function(Email,successFunction,failFunction,token) {
    var data = { 'interface': 'PickrWebService', 'method': 'CheckUserExistence', 'parameters': {'Email':Email}, 'token': token };

    var jsonData = dojo.toJson(data);
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: self.urlString,
        handleAs: 'json',
        postData: jsonData,
        load: successFunction,
        error: failFunction };
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
}
}
```

I need help on how to use this code in my client app, and what does the parameter 'token' refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a javascript object for you service which you can call the webservice, by invoking the methods. `token` is not the part of `dojo.xhrPost`, it might be from the ASP.Net for passing authentication token. If you have not setup the security on the service, you could ignore it.

```
var successFunction = function(args){
    //Handle the success response.
}

var failFunction= function(err){
    //Handle the failure response.
}

var service = new PickrWebService();
service.createUser(Email,Username,Password,
    FirstName,Surname,Birth,Gender,Mobile,Picture,Address,successFunction,failFunction);
```

Apart from the above code, you need to add the dojo api in you client.

Comment: Thank you, I used the following implementation : var service = new PickrWebService();
                    service.CheckUserExistence("ayman.khm@gmail.com", successFunction, failFunction, ""); and now I'm getting the XMLHttpRequest  error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, is there a workaround to avoid the same origin policy problem?

Comment: You need to enable cross domain on the server side, ie your asp.net rest api. Check IIS help on how to enable that.

Comment: Exactly! I nested the following lines in the Web.config file of my server side project: <system.webServer>
    ...<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>  and also headers: {
                                    "X-Requested-With": null
                                } in the xhrArgs passed to dojo.xhrPost() function in client side.